# Trying to replace a string in a file with values read from a different file in vbscript

Tags: loops, vbscript, scripting

I am new to scripting and I cannot figure out how to replace a string in a file with values read from a different file.  I have tried storing the values in an array and then plugging them into the replace method but I can't get the loops to work.  Here are two of my attempts:

```vb
Const ForReading = 1 

Const Inc = 0   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _ 
    ("ReadInFile.txt", ForReading)    

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream 

    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline 
    arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ",")
Loop 

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFile = "OrigFile.txt"

Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    If InStr(strLine,"777")> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"777",arrServiceList(Inc))    Inc = Inc + 1;
    End If 
Loop
```

---

```vb
Const ForReading = 1

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set answers     = fso.OpenTextFile("OrigFile.txt", ForReading)

Set fdf = fso.OpenTextFile("ReadInFile.txt", ForReading)

Set computers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Do Until answers.AtEndOfStream Or fdf.AtEndOfStream
  computers.Add names.ReadLine, locations.ReadLine

Loop

names.Close

locations.Close
```

I also tried a for each loop to read the array but I cannot incorporate it with the other loop.

Comment: please post (short) samples of input and (desired) output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some rebuilding with comment to help you on your way. Please try to understand each step.

```
Option Explicit     ' this makes sure you don't forget to declare variables
Const ForReading = 1 
Dim objFSO, objTextFile
Dim serviceCollection, service, strNextLine
Dim i    ' i is a variable, it get incremented. So don't make it a const
Dim strLine, objReadFile, objWriteFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
' An ArrayList let you .Add items to the collection without redimming it like a
' native array
Set serviceCollection = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("ReadInFile.txt", ForReading)    

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream ' Reads an textfile from start to end
    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline 
    for each service in Split(strNextLine , ",")   ' This splits a single line into parts on the comma character
        serviceCollection.Add service
    Next
Loop 

' Make an array from all services
arrServiceList = serviceCollection.ToArray()

Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("OrigFile.txt")
Set objWriteFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("NewFile.txt", true)

i = 0
Do Until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objReadFile.ReadLine

    If InStr(strLine,"777")> 0 Then
        ' This next line is not totally safe, because arrServiceList can go over its upperbound
        strLine = Replace(strLine, "777", arrServiceList(i))
        i = i + 1;
    End If 
    ' Important! Write the line to the new textfile
    objWriteFile.WriteLine strLine
Loop

' It is good practice to close opened files
objReadFile.Close
objWriteFile.Close
```

Still you can get some issues: When there are multiple `777`s on one line, they get replaced with the same variable because `i` is not incremented in the mean time. You could solve this by replacing it with something like

```
Do Until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objReadFile.ReadLine
    do
        If InStr(strLine,"777")> 0 Then
            strLine = Replace(strLine, "777", arrServiceList(i), 1, 1)
            i = i + 1;
            thereWasAReplace = True         '  do not forget to declare
        else
            thereWasAReplace = False
        End If 
    Loop While thereWasAReplace
    ' Write the line to the new textfile
    objWriteFile.WriteLine strLine
Loop
```

<sup>Disclaimer: I did this from the top of my head, so you can encounter a little bug or two.</sup>

Comment: condition "replacedLine = strLine" won't ever be True, because replacedLine is not changed in the loop and strLine won't become "".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Ah, yes, you are so right. Replaced it with a simpler, better to understand mechanism.